# Pros/Cons having majority of data in 1 object

Tags: javascript, performance

I have a web app that has several highcharts, several data tables, and configuration settings that go along with all of these. Currently I reference them through multiple variables. 
Like this:

```
var charts = {};//associative array of HighCharts
var tableInit = {};//table legend and other initialization data, also includes references to tables
var cache = {};//associative array of Table Cache
```

Would it be any better or worse to do something like this?

```
var data_store = {
    'tableInit' : {},//table legend and other initialization data
    'category' : {
        '-1' : {
            'chart' : $reference_to_Highchart,
            'table' : $reference_to_DataTable,
            'cache' : {}//object to store DataTable cache
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The less global variables, the better.

Comment: I would say the besides the consolidation, you are not cluttering the global namespace which prevent overwriting names from other devs \ libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually not a big deal. I mean I deal with VERY large json objects all the time, and I don't really have any problems regarding it. However, you might want to separate your data into different objects to make things more manageable. Other than that, most modern JS engines like V8 and OdinMonkey are very fast with objects.

Sometimes, it might clutter the global namespace, but if you do everything inside of an IFFE, then you really should not have any issues.

Comment: I also have to support back to IE7 so if its faster to do it one way or the other, I need to do that.